# How to execute a function concurrently in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, parallel-processing

In Python, I have a facility of multiprocessing API that takes a function name and parameter list as input and spawn processes based on the size you define. Say I have a function;

```
function viewSite(url) {
 console.log('Processing..'+url)  
 axios.get()...
}
```

If I have a list of 4 URLs, how do I spawn multiple processes that executes in separate process space?

Comment: It seems you need to use web workers and some package to ease your work with them, for instance `piscina`

Comment: Have you read https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html? Or https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html if you really need separate processes?

Comment: What do you actually want to do with those 4 urls? If it's just about loading them, you don't actually need multiple threads or even processes to do that concurrently in nodejs.

Comment: Nodejs can already run 4 axios calls in parallel just fine as they are asynchronous and non-blocking.  Just start them all one after another.  They will all be in flight and will each call their completion callback sometime later.  You don't need workerThreads or child processes for that.  You can use `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript will be interpreted and executed normally by one thread, there is no possibility to start threads like you want, but:

1. You could use worker threads https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html that have been added to distribute some work to different CPU cores (you don't need this in your case, there is no heavy calculation in your code)
2. You could use a new subprocess for this https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html that must be already available on your system. This is a bad idea, the complexity is too high
3. You should develop your code asynchronously and use async/await like:

```
async function viewSite(url) {
    console.log('Processing..'+url);
    try{
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        return res.data;
    } catch(error){
        // do something or throw error;
    }
}

async function collectAllSitesData(){

  const results = await Promise.all([viewSite(url1),viewSite(url2),...]);

  // do something with results here, not after call of collectAllSitesData()
}

collectAllSitesData();
```

async functions return a Promise, so check how to work with async-approach, for example: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: @jfriend00 It returns the `.data` after waiting for the promise result. And it handles rejections of the promise.

Comment: @optb `await is only valid in async function`. I got this message

Comment: @Volatil3 yes, you need some async function where you use `await Promise.all(...)`
this would be the same like with `async function viewSite(){...}`, for example:
```
async function main(){
const results = await Promise.all([viewSite(url1),viewSite(url2),...]);
// do something
}
main();
```

Comment: @Volatil3 I updated the description in my answer